# How can I change the temporary file directory path without the UI?

Tags: 8

In Drupal 8, Is there any way to change the temporary file directory path if I don't have access to the UI page `/admin/config/media/file-system`, either with Drush or by modifying a config file?

Answer (score 20, accepted):

### Drush

`drush config:set system.file path.temporary /tmp -y`

### settings.php

If done through `settings.php` it will no longer be changeable via either the interface or Drush.

#### Drupal 8.8+

See the [change record](https://www.drupal.org/node/3039255).

```php
$settings['file_temp_path'] = '/tmp';
```

#### Drupal 8.7 and below

```php
$config['system.file']['path']['temporary'] = '/tmp';
```